# how to creat a mklink /J but don't delete content in the copied folder even I delete the "root" content

Tags: cmd, mklink

I am trying to run the following command:

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\to 117" C:\Users\xx\Desktop\117
```

but once the content in `117` gets deleted, the `to 117` also gets deleted.

Any suggestions for me if I delete the `117` content but the `to 117` content would not delete?